# Sorting works only once

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have GridView with sorting, it works quite well, but it works only once, and yes this is not a duplicate I found lot of question, but it doesn't help me. Please what is wrong that it sort only once (like a direction is not changing) ?

```
        ViewState["sort"] = "ASC" --> is declared in PageLoad

        protected void grid_sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e) 
        {
            DataView sorting = new DataView(data); //data is global DataTable

            if (ViewState["sort"].ToString() == "ASC")
                ViewState["sort"] = "DESC";
            else
                ViewState["sort"] = "ASC";

            sorting.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ViewState["sort"];
            data = sorting.ToTable();
            GridView1.DataSource = data;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All objects are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle, so when it's rendered as HTML and sent to the client. So you can't use the field `string direction = "ASC"` to store the sort direction. That will be initialized to `"ASC"` on every postback.

Instead you have to use a different way, for example:

- Session
- ViewState
- HiddenField

[ASP.NET State Management Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

Comment: I updated my post, but it doesn't work, at second click nothing happens

Comment: @tomsk: you have updated your question but it's not clear what code you use now. What is declared in `PageLoad`?

Comment: I added into PageLoad this: ViewState["sort"] = "ASC";

Comment: @tomsk: then change it to `if(!IsPostBack)ViewState["sort"] = "ASC";`